# How to show my Keyboard extension's Emojis in other device

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-keyboard-extension

I am looking for the solution for iOS Keyboard extensions.

My problem is if I will type My Emojis using my device, so how the another device (who does not have installed my app) will be able to show that in app like Whatsapp.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing many research I concluded that what I was expecting is currently not possible.

But this is possible that,

If I will create my own emoji keyboard, then clicking on that emoji in Keyboard extension will copy that image.

After paste that image to any textfield of apps like Whatsapp, I will be only able to share that emoji as Image.(i.e. Image sharing).

Making your own emojis like native emojis is currently not possible to be available in all public apps.

We can do this for only our apps, like Skype and Hike does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Emoji Unicode
[link](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)

Example

```
   NSString *str = @"Hi \U0001F431";

    NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *valueUnicode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSData *newData = [valueUnicode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *valueEmoj = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:newData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

    lbl.text = valueEmoj;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am looking for another thing.
What I want is, I want to show my own custom emojis not those in link.